.Net Core 8 Binding Redirect
I have a simple scenario where one of the nuget package A1 is referring to  version v1 of a nuget package B1, my project is refering to a newer version v2 of package B1. I want that the nuget package should use v2 instead of v1. In .Net framework we have binding redirect for this but not sure how to make it work in .net core 8.
